# When you make your iPhone app free from paid does it appear on the 'new' list?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I'm just curious, if I have an app that's paid on the store and has been for months if I switch it to 'free' does it go back on the 'new releases' list for free apps or does it just get switched to free wherever it is?

Comment: No it does not appear as new.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the price will simply change. **Changing the price will remove your app from the Top Listings though (if in it).**

If you want your app to appear in the Newly Released list, then release an update to your app.

Comment: oh right thanks :) I was just curious because I switched my paid app to free and the downloads jumped 200% I wanted to know if that was caused by it simply because it was getting more exposure despite its low ranking now that it's free or because it was reshown in the 'newly released' section.

What do you mean when you say it will be removed from the 'top listings'? Do you mean if my app is #1 in 'free' and I make it paid it won't become #1 in paid but just entirely unranked and have to climb again to the top?

Comment: That is correct. If Angry Birds was changed to a free app, it would be removed from the top paid section and it would have to reclimb up to the top of the free section. Btw, your downloads jumped because the app was changed you free. There are a LOT more downloads when the app is free, even if it was previously $0.99 (requiring money is a subconscious roadblock for many people). Let me know if you have any other questions!

Comment: That is a tiny jump.  Making a paid app free often increases the daily download count by 10x to 20x.  And cause a drop in the new rankings.

Comment: @hotpaw2 True, take what you want from it. If you go in the opposite direction (free to paid), you probably won't have the same luck. Thanks for pointing that out though.

Comment: @hotpaw2, my math is awful, it actually went up from 2 downloads to 50 on the first day, then the following day to 200, lack of sleep makes me really bad at maths :-/

Comment: wat if i have a app released in app store which is free,and later i want to set price for that app. how can i do that??

Comment: @sujay Go to "Rights and Pricing" and raise the price.

Answer (score 2):

No it does not, seeing as you are only changing the price of any existing app. Where as if you released a 1.1 then it would be considered a new release.